# Nao robot not walking with arms pointing in front of him

Tags: nao-robot

I've been working in Choregraphe to make the Nao push a light object. Now whenever I put him in a position with his arms stretched in front of him he doesn't want to move forward ( no objects in front of him, so no anti-collision ). He just makes one small step, followed by Choregraphe catching the onStoppedBeforeArriving from the 'Move To' box. 
Although when his arms are pointing to his left and right hand-side he has no problems with walking.

Could this be because he needs a certain balance before he starts to walk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Ultrasound (sonar) is seeing obstacles (his arms) so the walk is stopped.

You can remove this by disabling external collision:

motion.setExternalCollisionProtectionEnabled( "All", False )

NB: on some naoqi version, you'll have to check some option in the robot web page to activate the rights to disable collision...

Comment: Yes, I got it working by programming the yaw, rolls and pitches of the arms in python script instead of using an animation in Choregraphe. This combined with what you said made him push a box with his arms pointing in front of him. Thanks for the help.